# How to add foreign keys MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

MySQL keeps returning 'cannot add foreign key constraint'.

The tables are deleted at each execution before being remade.

Currently after all the tables are made, I try to alter the tables to include foreign keys; I have tried adding the keys when the tables are created, but the program returns the same error.

I'm sure each column being referenced have identical values too.

```
CREATE TABLE utopia.student (id_student VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL, 
    Student_Name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, Degree VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id_student));
 -- Create Student Table
CREATE TABLE utopia.module (id_module VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL, 
    Module_Name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, Credits Int NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id_module));
-- Create Module Table
 CREATE TABLE utopia.registered (id_student VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL, 
      id_module VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id_student, id_module));
-- Create Registered Table
CREATE TABLE utopia.staff (id_staff VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL, 
    Staff_Name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, Grade VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id_staff));
-- Create Staff Table
CREATE TABLE utopia.teaches (id_staff VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL, 
     id_module VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id_staff, id_module)); 
-- Create Teaches Table

ALTER TABLE utopia.student ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_student) 
    REFERENCES registered(id_student);
ALTER TABLE utopia.module ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_module) 
    REFERENCES registered(id_module);
ALTER TABLE utopia.registered ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_student) 
    REFERENCES  student(id_student), 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_module) 
    REFERENCES module(id_module);
ALTER TABLE utopia.staff ADD FOREIGN KEY idstaff REFERENCES teaches(id_staff);
ALTER TABLE utopia.teaches ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_staff) REFERENCES staff(id_staff), 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_module) REFERENCES module(id_module);
```

Any advice/tutorials on the subject would be appreciated

Comment: Which MySQL version? Which storage engine: MyISAM or INNODB?

Comment: I think your foreign keys are backwards.  `registered` needs a foreign key to to `student` and another foreign key to `module`. Your example is trying to put a foreign key on the wrong table.  Make sense?  In other words which comes first: `student` or `registered`?  Since the `student` record comes first, `registered` has a foreign key to student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a foreign key the parent table`s column must be primary or unique at least.In `registered` table `id_module` is part of a composite key and that doesn't cut it,just add an uniqe key on it.You also have some missing parentheses.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1cfba)

Comment: I thought all the columns I was making foreign keys were already primary keys in the other tables?
Also, why can't a foreign key be a part of a composite key?

Comment: @OneGlove I think it might be able to reference the column of a composite primary key if the referenced column is first,I`m not sure.

Answer (score -1):

```
**use following command syntax**
```

ALTER TABLE table_name ADD FOREIGN KEY column_name(column_name) REFERENCES table_name(column_name)

**Example**

```
ALTER TABLE utopia.student ADD FOREIGN KEY utopia.student.id_student(id_student_fck01) 
REFERENCES utopia.registered(utopia.registered.id_student);
```

Comment: So using the student table as an example, it should be: 
**ALTER TABLE student ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_student) REFERENCES registered(id_student)**